# Including data and vignette in package? Problems with size

Tags: r, package

I have been working on an R package. A package deals with large data (more than 200-300mb is the data file that is used in vignette example, however, when compressed, the whole package is about 20-30mb). If I would use smaller data, an example in vignette would not make any sense.

Since I plan to upload this to a CRAN, what should I do? I read that you need to "justify the size of your package" and "If it’s still too large, consider moving data into its own package." (this is from R packages by Hadley Wickham). What does this mean?

When running check as cran, I get a note about package size (0 errors and 0 warnings). It doesn't seem like the package is that big and it is impossible to include less data because test example in vignette would not make any sense. Is this a valid reason for having package size larger than 5mb or will it be turned down from cran?

I thought about putting this data on my private server and loading it over the internet (for example read.tabe(file="https://link_to_file....")) in vignette Rmd. However, I found out that all the data for creating a vignette has to be in vignettes folder.

Then I thought about excluding the vignette, pkgdown site and the data (and .r file describing this data in R folder) from the build and submitting the package as it is to cran (with no vignette and data). Furthermore, I would put the vignette, pkgdown site and the data on another github repository available for everybody, providing the link in README file. 
Does this make sense to you? By proceeding this way I would have a package which, if tested, would give 0 errors, warnings and notes but without complete documentation (however, I would provide it over github repo). 
What do you think? Does submitting a package without vignette increases chances of being turned down (even though you have 0 errors/warnings/notes in a check)? Or should I include the vignette but then have a > 5mb package (which returns 1 note in check)? Is there a way to submit a package with a vignette but without the data but still provide the data separately?
I have no idea how to proceed. Any suggestions are welcome, thank you...

Comment: CRAN doesn't enforce having a vignette in your package. Many (most?) packages don't have vignettes. I wouldn't include such a large file just for a vignette and I'm not yet convinced that it is even necessary in your case. Can't you simulate data for your vignette?

Comment: The package is created to process the data that is the output of a hardware system we built. Data could be simulated but it would still be too large. If we simulated smaller data, an example in vignette wouldn't make any sense. 

I guess sending a package without data and vignette to cran and also providing test data for users to download and hosting a pkgdown site (including a vignette as an example on how to use a package) is a way to go here?

Comment: Presumably you are doing some computations on the big dataset, and displaying the results of those.  Why not include the object holding the computation result in your package, with instructions on how to reproduce it by downloading the full dataset and running the code?  Your vignette will be self-contained and small.  BTW, it's a *very good* idea to include a vignette.  Packages without them are harder to use and look unfinished, just like other cases of poor documentation.

Comment: Re Hadley's recommendation to create a "data package" for your data that your focal package depends on: https://thecoatlessprofessor.com/programming/r/creating-an-r-data-package/